# SQL Server restarts, unable to find the reason

Tags: sql-server

One of our SQL Server instances restarts itself in a clustered environment, but it is not fail-overed. When I checked the error logs, event viewer and cluster log I'm unable to find any particular reason for what it causing these restarts, but in failover cluster manager --> Roles --> Critical events I found this error:

[image]

> Cluster resource 'SQL Server' of type 'SQL Server' in clustered role 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)' failed
>
> Based on the failure policies for the resource and role, the cluster service may try to bring the resource online on this node or move the group to another node of the cluster and then restart it. Check the resource and group state using Failover Cluster Manager or the Get-ClusterResource Windows PowerShell cmdlet.

Can I know if there is any specific reason for SQL Server restarts with the above error or is there anything we can configure for the SQL Server error logs to capture the errors of these restarts or failovers or any audits?

1. Both Windows servers are not rebooted
2. Server is physical server
3. It is an Active/Pasive clustered environment
4. Both servers are running on Windows Server 2012 R2
5. Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows
6. I verified the all the 6 errorlogs  and events in event viewer and cluster.log file also

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will not find that much in a regular errorlog.

Therefore, specialized diagnostic logs to be reviewed:

```
ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION SET DIAGNOSTICS LOG ON;
```

Then

```sql
SELECT  
xml_data.value('(event/@name)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'Name'  
,xml_data.value('(event/@package)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'Package'  
,xml_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]','datetime') AS 'Time'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''state'']/value)[1]','int') AS 'State'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''state_desc'']/text)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'State Description'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''failure_condition_level'']/value)[1]','int') AS 'Failure Conditions'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''node_name'']/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'Node_Name'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''instancename'']/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'Instance Name'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''creation time'']/value)[1]','datetime') AS 'Creation Time'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''component'']/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'Component'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''data'']/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'Data'  
,xml_data.value('(event/data[@name=''info'']/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'Info'  
FROM  
 ( SELECT object_name AS 'event'  
  ,CONVERT(xml,event_data) AS 'xml_data'  
  FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\SQLNODE1_MSSQLSERVER_SQLDIAG_0_129936003752530000.xel',NULL,NULL,NULL)   
)   
AS XEventData  
ORDER BY Time;
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/view-and-read-failover-cluster-instance-diagnostics-log?view=sql-server-ver15

Alternatively, to access and review existing cluster logs:

```bsh
Import-Module FailoverClusters   
Get-ClusterLog -TimeSpan 15 -Destination .
```

And the old-school way, on one of the nodes using command shell with elevated permissions:

```
cluster log /g
```